# [RUBY]Server/Client | Command Client to start Using function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I am working on some stupid simulation of mining cryptocoins - just for fun.
But I have run into an issue I want to command the client to start using a function but I am not sure how to do it, my code is bellow for Server.rb and Client.rb

Client

```
require 'socket'

s = TCPSocket.new 'localhost', 2626

while line = s.gets
    puts line
end

s.close
```

Server.rb

```
#!/bin/ruby

require "socket"
require 'securerandom'


PORT = 2626
server_pool = TCPServer.open(PORT)

sndc_block_time = 200    # Size of block
sndc_block_time = 10        # Time to brake block 1,1 out of 200, 200    

sndc_coin_blocks= 126^2     # Ammount of available blocks
sndc_coin_balance = 0

sub_blocks = 0      # Sub blocks user wants to mine

addr = SecureRandom.hex # generate a random hexadecimal address

# Notify message shown when user registers a new address
disclaimer = "Welcome to the SendCoin Network!
A new address has been registered and saved
to your computer desktop!"


def handle_connection(client)
  puts "New client! #{client} \n\n"

end

puts "Listening on #{PORT}. Press CTRL+C to cancel."

while client = server_pool.accept
  if Thread.new { handle_connection(client) }

  if sndc_coin_blocks < 126^2 / 4
    sndc_coin_blocks + 126^2 / 4    # Add a quarter of the original size
  end

  if Dir['../MyAddress/*.addr'].any? == true

    # Statrs Mining
    client.puts "Starting to mine.."
    sleep(5)
    client.puts "Current blocks: " + sndc_coin_blocks.to_s
    client.puts "Block Size: " + sndc_coin_balance.to_s
    client.puts "Approximate time to mine 1 sub-block: " + sndc_block_time.to_s
    client.puts "Searching for block.."
    sleep(3)
    if sndc_block_time != 10
      sndc_block_time = 10
    end
    client.puts "Started mining..." 


  elsif Dir['../addresses/*.addr'].any? == false
    File.open("../addresses/"+addr+".addr", "w") do |f|    # Create file    
      f.write(sndc_coin_balance.to_s)   
    end

    client.puts "New address generated: " + addr.to_s + " , you may realunch the app now and enter your address!"

    # Start Mining
    puts "> File 'address.addr' has been generated for#{client}"
  end

end
end
```

So essentially I want after this line of code:

```
client.puts "Started mining..."
```

.. to command the client to (client.rb) to start using a function.

Comment: It would help if you could reduce the code down to just show the problem you are having... I don't think there is any need for any of the pseudo-bitcoin stuff?

Comment: Yeah, sure I can reduce code. and it is just for personal use just experimenting let's say.

Comment: Well the main idea is that I want a function to be executed on the client.rb when the server.rb file decides to.